# How to get count of keys in store1 in redis db1

Tags: redis

How to get count of keys in store1 in redis db1 database?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXYzA.png)

commant "count keys store1" not working. please help

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command to calculate length is based on the type, if the type is hash then **HLEN key** will return the length of the hash. If the type is list then **LLEN key** will return the length and similarly **STRLEN key** will return the size/length of the string type.

To identify the type you can use **TYPE key** command and used the respective length command to get the size.